# kubernetes plugin in jenkins is not working, Test connection is failing

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, amazon-eks

**Environment running:**

My Jenkins master is running in the EC2 instance. Jenkins version:- `Jenkins 2.249.1`

My Kubernetes cluster is running in `EKS`

I have installed the Kubernetes plugin(1.27.7) and trying to create a Jenkins agent in k8's. I have created a service account, role, role binding. My Yaml file looks as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins-admin
  namespace: default
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: default
  labels:
    "app.kubernetes.io/name": 'jenkins'
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins-role-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins-admin
  namespace: default
```

In Place of the default namespace, I have given a specific namespace

Below is the attached screenshots of My configuration
I have added credentials as the secret text

[image]

---

[image]

Error it is throwing:

> Error testing connection https://xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/.kube/config (No such file or directory)

Comment: have you added kubeconfig file to jenkins credentials ?

Comment: I have added service account token as secret text in Jenkins credentials

Comment: When I add kubeconfig file and test connection, Getting following error
Error testing connection https://xxxxxxx.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com: Failure executing: GET at: https://xxxxxxxx.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/pie-automation/pods. Message: pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "pie-automation". Received status: Status(apiVersion=v1, code=403, details=StatusDetails(causes=[], group=null,

Comment: `When I add …following error…` don't hide essential information in comments: Edit your question.

Comment: @greybeard I had hidden cluster URL only. I have added full error comment

Comment: Any solution for the above ?